# Gamepad + Keyboard Virtual Joystick

Tags: keyboard, joystick, gamepad

I have been searching the website for the perfect software that maps keyboard keystrokes to real game pad key presses. 
I found various softwares like JoytoKey , Xpadder , Vjoy and Universal Joystick Remapper. But the thing is none of them combines inputs from the keyboard and binds them with keys of the gamepad.

Does anyone know any software that merges keyboard keys and the gamepads to make a virtual controller so that it can be used in games.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, VJoy is a perfect solution for your problem (reboot required) - it emulates gamepad/joystick through key presses on a real keyboard, but... for some reason it's not working in _my_ application - the joystick input isn't fetched, although the keys are properly assigned via VJoy to the gamepad, yet with a real device (gamepad with x360) the input is fetched properly, which leads me to an idea that the driver is somehow using some old method or a completely different layout from the devices that are used now because → key is blocked, but no expected input is recieved.

Comment: And that leads me to another emulator I know about [x360CE](https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce), which should do the thing for xbox gamepads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about emulating mouse, keyboard or gamepads, and not just getting limited by mouse and keyboard emulation provided by most applications.

For a software to emulate a gamepad, it needs to install its own gamepad driver or fake a DirectInput or XInput library and install it on the target application's directory for it to work. Either options require low level programming and are hard to develop, so a software with this functionality is also hard to find.

I never used a software to emulate a gamepad directly, but I heard about **GlovePIE**. GlovePIE is scriptable, so you can make it do anything in any way you want and you can emulate any device with any device; for example, you can emulate a gamepad with a keyboard, a mouse with a gamepad, a MIDI controller with a gamepad, etc.

Right now, it seems that GlovePIE web page is having problems, but you can search about it on Internet.

Here, you can get it along with more information on how to use it:

https://www.engadget.com/2007/06/12/revolutionary-introducing-glovepie/